# How do I sync users and passwords from active directory to FreeIPA?

Tags: active-directory, freeipa

So I have an active directory domain, call it foo.com.  Two server 2019 servers as DCs.  I'm trying to move away from windows, to FreeIPA.  I have a handful of users who login to a webmail server, which authenticates to the AD domain.  All working fine.  I don't know their passwords, nor do I want to.  What I would *like* to do is (somehow) have one of the AD controllers sync the passwords to the FreeIPA instance.  Syncing the entire user is nice, but not necessary, since I can create the users manually.  I freely admit I don't really grok how trusts work, but I thought I read that to set up a trust between FreeIPA and AD, they had to be in non-overlapping domains.  If so, that's a deal-breaker, because the whole point here is that I want to replace AD servicing foo.com with FreeIPA servicing foo.com.  As a last-ditch, I'm prepared to notify them that I'm changing their passwords to temporary ones, and as soon as I cut over, they can change their passwords back, but that's obviously less than ideal.  Any helpful tips much appreciated!

Comment: You need to describe the actual reasoning behind what your are trying to achieve. Generally, AD can't sync passwords because they are not stored in clear-text. Also, it is not obvious what are the capabilities you would like to move to a 3rd-party product, which might not even be possible to achieve with FreeIPA. This of course depends on your requirements and environment, which are currently not clear

Comment: From what I've read, if you set up a trust between freeipa and AD, the hashed passwords *are* synced.  Except, as I said, I was told 'non-overlapping domains', which is a deal-breaker for me.  I'm trying to migrate users&passwords off the AD servers, since I want to move away from windows.  If I could somehow sync the users&passwords (there is nothing complicated here - a handful of usernames&passwords), I could then decommission the AD servers.